# Why do I get access denied for sectors 16 and above?

Tags: winapi, io

I am using CreateFile, ReadFile and WriteFile to access a disk's sectors directly. It looks like I can read any sector I want, but when it comes to writing, I get ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED for sectors 16 and above. I am at a loss to explain why I can write to the first 15 sectors but not the others.

This is on Windows 10.

Note that I have not tried every single sector above 16, just a random sampling of them and they all seem to fail.

```
int wmain(int argc, WCHAR *argv[])
    {
    HANDLE hDisk = NULL;
    hDisk = CreateFile(
                L"\\\\.\\Q:",
                GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
                FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
                NULL,
                OPEN_EXISTING,
                0,
                NULL);

    char *rgb = (char *) malloc(512);
    BOOL b = FALSE;
    DWORD dw = 0;
    LONG lo = 0;
    LONG hi = 0;

    for(int i=0; i<20; i++)
        {
        hi = 0;
        lo = i * 512;

        dw = SetFilePointer(hDisk, lo, &hi, FILE_BEGIN);
        b = ReadFile(hDisk, rgb, 512, &dw, NULL);
        if (b == FALSE)
            printf("Cannot read sector %d\r\n", i);

        hi = 0;
        lo = i * 512;

        dw = SetFilePointer(hDisk, lo, &hi, FILE_BEGIN);
        b = WriteFile(hDisk, rgb, 512, &dw, NULL);
        if (b == FALSE)
            printf("Cannot write sector %d\r\n", i);
        }

    return 0;
    }
```

The code above outputs:

```
Cannot write sector 16
Cannot write sector 17
Cannot write sector 18
Cannot write sector 19
```

I've omitted error handling code to keep things short.

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem.
Because I opened the drive with FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, I was denied access to the part of the disk that contained a volume that was in use.
At least, that's my educated guess.

Once I removed the SHARE flags and made sure I had sole access to the drive, I could read and write any sector.